# Javascript/Discord.js-How do I make a bot only respond to a message if it contains a specific word and does not have letters around it

Tags: javascript, input, discord.js

```
client.on("messageCreate", message => {

    let string = message.content;

    string = string.toLowerCase();

    if (string.indexOf("andy") >= 0) {
        message.channel.send("Test")
    }

})
```

I was wondering how one would make the code not send "test" if string would be a string like candy where it responds as if the string is andy. I would like it to only respond if the string is andy and not if the string has letters around it which change the meaning of the word.

I am sorry for this basic question but I did not know how to word it when searching for it. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be done by simply checking if the message content matched and includes. By putting a space before and after it will only look for that word if it isn't part of another word like candy or randy.

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async message => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(' andy ')) {
        message.channel.send("Test")
    }
})
```